# In PHP, how can I remove items in an array whose keys are found in another array conveniently?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$array = new Array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'Peter', 'sex'=>'male', 'age'=>25);

$excludes = new Array('sex', 'age');
```

I want to get the following result:

```
$array = new Array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'Peter');
```

The items whose keys are found in the array $excludes are removed.

How can I achieve this conveniently?

Comment: For loop and unset by the keys ?

Comment: Thank you! But I want a more convenient method. In fact, there has been one, contributed by @RomanPerekhrest. You can see his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply with `array_diff_key` and `array_flip` functions:

```
// $arr is your initial array (besides, don't give `$array` name to arrays)
$result = array_diff_key($arr, array_flip($excludes));
print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Peter
)
```

Comment: Wow! That's cool! That's what I want! Thank you so much! I'm excited to get this wonderful answer so soon! Really really thank you!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have a question is this way is more efficient then just make for loop ?

Comment: @Avihaym, for such "small" input arrays - the difference won't be essential and critical. We may start benchmarking when dealing with big arrays (thousands/millions items)

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeExcludesFromArray($input,$expludes) {
    $newArray = array(); // Create a new empty array
    foreach($array as $inputKey => $inputElement) { // loop your original array
        if(!array_key_exists($inputKey,$excludes)) { // check if key exists
             $newArray[$inputKey] = $inputElement; // add on demand
         }
     }

     return $newArray; // return the result
}


// Call the function
$array = removeExcludesFromArray($array,$excludes);
```

Comment: It's always better to use functionality already provided by PHP itself, see the other answer.

Comment: Thank you! But I want a more convenient method. In fact, there has been one, contributed by @RomanPerekhrest. You can see his answer. Anyway, thank you very much for your help!